# How can I make a form that is not disabled when another form is shown modally?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl

I have a utility dialog (non-modal and stay-on-top) that should be accessible at all times when using the application (think of a dialog that can be used to take notes while working with the application) **even if a modal dialog is displayed**.

The rest of the application cannot be changed.

Is it possible? How could I go about it?

Comment: 'Modality' in Windows can indeed be a PITA. (The worst example I can think of is Microsoft Word 2010, where you cannot open a Word document (e.g. by double-clicking a *.docx file) if some other Word window has a modal dialog open.) Perhaps your utility form could be part of a different application?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: I thought about making it a separate application but I need to have access to the applications internals (for some capture / replay mechanism).

Comment: Using named pipes for communication between two applications is pretty easy. Look at [cromis-ipc](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-ipc/) for a good start.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: is that a "no, not possible" from you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When `ShowModal` is called, all existing top level windows are disabled. That's how modality is meant to work. If you have a window with which interaction is reasonable, you just need to enable it again.

For example, you could add this to your utility window:

```
type
  TMyUtilityForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure WMEnable(var Message: TWMEnable); message WM_ENABLE;
  end;
....
procedure TMyUtilityForm.WMEnable(var Message: TWMEnable);
begin
  if not Message.Enabled then
    EnableWindow(Handle, True);
  inherited;
end;
```

This will make sure that your utility window can never be disabled.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Very nice of you to say so, and I can only wish it were actually true!  ;-)

Comment: I'd use a `WM_ENABLE` handler, and a call to `EanbleWindow()` before the inherited call. Would look more natural.

Comment: @Sertac I agree that this mechanism to avoid disabling could be cleaner. I just put in the first idea that came into my head to demonstrate the basic concept.

Comment: +1 David, thank you so much for this! This works nicely and saves me so much effort. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would add `if not IsWindowEnabled(Handle)` however, because otherwise it starts to look like an infinite loop, even though `EnableWindow(Handle, True)` probably won't result in a `WM_ENABLE` to be sent in case the window is already enabled.

Comment: @tvdien Done. It's actually easiest to read the Enabled state out of the message that is passed to you. And no, there's no infinite recursion here. `EnableWindow` only leads to `WM_ENABLE` if the state is being altered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I know that this wasn't in the original question, but the above doesn't work with MDI. With MDI, the WMEnable handler of the non-modal never seems to be called. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @No'am Perhaps a new question?