# How do I make a dialog modal with respect to some, but not all, of the program's other windows?

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog, delphi-xe2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a form that is not disabled when another form is shown modally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953225/how-can-i-make-a-form-that-is-not-disabled-when-another-form-is-shown-modally)

Suppose I have an application with three forms: a main form that leads the user through a workflow, wizard style; a modal window that shows occasionally in certain steps of the wizard; and a third "information" window, which could show at any time, independent of where in the workflow the user is.

How do I make the modal window grab focus away from the main form, but keep the info window usable and responsive at all times?

Using the most obvious `InfoFrame.Create(nil).Show` from the main frame leaves the info window unusable when the modal form is showing.

Curiously, if I create and show the info window from the modal window, it will be responsive in the desired way, and it persists after the modal window is dismissed. When the modal window is shown again, though, the info window is forced into the background and becomes unresponsive.

How do I make the info windows remain usable at all times, even when another form's `ShowModal` procedure has been called?

<sub>In the actual application I'm working on, there are actually tens of modal forms from about a dozen 'workflow' main windows (many of them are also modal), but only one info window (of which multiple instances may be shown),  I'd prefer not to have to change every call to ShowModal to something else, although I'm not averse to wrapping or subclassing the call if that's the only option.</sub>

Comment: Not very practical, but if your _info_ window is just for information purposes, perhaps you can create it using `winapi` and leave it out of `Application`'s domain.

Comment: To be clear, if you have two "main" windows and one "info" window, and one of those main windows creates a modal dialog, you do want to disable the other main window, just not the info window?

Comment: right, everything besides the info window(s) and the newly opened modal form should be disabled.

Comment: @iMan That won't work. ShowModal will disable all top level windows, whether or not they are VCL windows.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My mistake. I thought perhaps `Application` can't access windows out of its reach.

Comment: @iMan - The windows belonging with the same thread with the modal form are disabled.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `ShowModal`, but instead disable the `MainForm` using `EnableWindow(MainForm.Handle, False)` and enable it again afterwards using `EnableWindow(MainForm.Handle, True)`. You might need to add something to make sure that the right window is always on top.

Edit: If you don't want to change anything in the `MainForm`, nor in the modal form, you can add a Timer to the `InfoFrame` that has that form constantly enable itself:

```
procedure TInfoFrame.EnablerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not IsWindowEnabled(Self.Handle) then
    EnableWindow(Self.Handle, True);
end;
```

That way, the `InfoFrame` will be usable even after a call to `ShowModal` of another form.

Edit2: As pointed out by @DavidHeffernan, rather than in a Timer, a better place to put this logic would be in the `WM_ENABLE` handler of the `InfoFrame`. The idea remains the same, though.

Comment: Sorry, the application in question uses `ShowModal` in more than 500 locations;  it's not feasible for me to figure out how to 'almost show modal' that many times.  I need a solution that extends existing behaviour.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy So basically you're asking for some kind of hack. Well, I edited my post.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I've already pointed you at that solution I think.

Comment: @DavidHeffeman Well, partially true. The difference is that the way I used it, you don't need to change any other forms.

Comment: @tvdien A timer isn't so great. Have a read of my answer again. I followed Sertac's advice and did it in a `WM_ENABLE` message handler.

Comment: @DavidHefferman True, I couldn't think of a better place to put it that quickly. I agree that `WM_ENABLE` is a better choice. I suggest you make that an answer and I'll put a reference to it in mine.

Comment: @tvdien I'm not going to add an answer since this question is an exact duplicate. What we do in that situation is close the question as being a duplicate. The idea is that we can have just a single topic for each distinct question. If you want to answer the question, it's better to do so at the original location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953225/how-can-i-make-a-form-that-is-not-disabled-when-another-form-is-shown-modally?lq=1

Comment: @DavidHeffeman Very well then...

Comment: By the way, I upvoted your answer because it is a good answer. And I'm not trying to put you off. You've not been very active yet on SO and I suspect you aren't familiar with the intricacies of close votes and so on. So I'm just trying to help.

Comment: @DavidHefferman No problem. I don't mind giving credit where it is due, especially if it is to someone with a track record like yours. :) It makes sense to keep organized.

Comment: In the case of using `WM_ENABLE` here, the real credit goes to Sertac Akyuz! He's the no. 1 Windows API expert in the Delphi tags in my opinion.

Comment: @David - Heh, heh.. wish it were so, nice dream for me :D

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just noticed that I had been misspelling your name all along. My apologies - unfortunately I'm unable to edit those comments anymore.

Comment: @tvdien It's fine. I've spent a lifetime having my name misspelled. You are not the first and won't be the last to call me Hefferman!  ;-)